# Setting timezone in Protractor e2e tests

Tags: javascript, datetime, cucumber, protractor, e2e-testing

I have some Protractor e2e tests in which I deal with timezone.
On my local machine they pass, on Appveyor they don't.

I found out it's a timezone setting issue (different settings on Appveyor).

Is there a way to set the timezone at the start of the test suite and bring it back the old one at the end?

I tried this solution (so please don't mark this as duplicate):
[Set browser timezone in a Protractor test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341059/set-browser-timezone-in-a-protractor-test)

which I found to be a very ugly workaround. Anything prettier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PowerShell to update the timezone and reset it after. This can be achieved using [AppVeyor environment variables](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables/), [Get-TimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-timezone?view=powershell-6) & [Set-TimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-timezone?view=powershell-6). Here is an `appveyor.yml` sample:

```
init:
  - ps: $env:ORIGIONAL_TZ = Get-TimeZone
  - ps: Set-TimeZone -Name "Pacific Standard Time"

on_finish:
  - ps: Set-TimeZone -Name $env:ORIGIONAL_TZ
```