# Change the timezone from windows on the fly using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am facing some challenges to find a better way to test timezones, what is happening now is:

I have a report with some links (for detailed data), when the user access this report comes the transaction date as one of the columns (lets say its today 11th)
When the user clicks at one of these links to have more details about the transaction, the user is transferred to the detail page.

The bug is, when the timezone is UTC-04 the user gets the date of 10th instead of 11th, it only works properly with the UTC+2

I have tried to mock the change of timezone using this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone-mock

But didn't work as I wanted, the date is changed but the bug doesn't happen.

It is possible to reproduce this only when I change manually the timezone from windows.

I also found the possibility of using powershell commands to do this

[Setting timezone in Protractor e2e tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608908/setting-timezone-in-protractor-e2e-tests?noredirect=1&lq=1)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell

So far I could not make it work.

The question is, is it possible to automate the change of window's (system) timezone somehow?

Ty!

Comment: Hi @Kacper as I understood this only changes/format the string right? What I need is actually change the timezone from the system

Comment: Maybe it's something more useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32335796/6331748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some time trying and failing.. found this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2556308/tzutil-command-line-tool-is-added-to-windows-vista-and-to-windows-serv

tzutil.exe works for windows 10 and windows server as well, it is really simple to execute, the function needs to be like this:

```
    browser.controlFlow().execute(() => {
        var child_process = require('child_process');
        console.log(String(child_process.exec('tzutil /s "Eastern Standard Time')));
    });
```

This changes automatically the timezone from the system.