# Using TimeShift.js in end to end Protractor tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm trying to use [TimeShift.js](https://github.com/plaa/TimeShift-js) to mock the standard Javascript Date. This way I can specify a TimeZone instead of using the system one.

The documentation seems to be very clear, just `require` the library and use it like this:

```
Date = TimeShift.Date;
TimeShift.setTimezoneOffset(-300);
TimeShift.setTime(1275393600000);
new Date().toString();
// => "Tue Jun 01 2010 17:00:00 GMT+0500"
```

However I get a TypeError "undefined is not a function". What I'm doing wrong here? This is the complete `step.js` file:

```
var chai        = require('chai');
var chaiPromise = require("chai-as-promised");
var HttpBackend = require('http-backend-proxy');
var utils       = require('../utils.js');
var timeshift   = require('../TimeShift.js');
var expect      = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiPromise);
var fs = require('fs');

var steps = function() {
    var proxy = null;

    this.Before(function(scenario, callback) {
        proxy = new HttpBackend(browser);

        Date = timeshift.Date;
        timeshift.setTimezoneOffset(-300);
        timeshift.setTime(1275393600000);

        callback();
    });

    this.After(function(scenario, callback) {
        proxy.onLoad.reset();
        callback();
    });
}

module.exports = steps;
```

**EDIT:**

even running the plain tests.html straight away from a fresh copy of develop gives me the undefined error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue with Timeshift when using it inside protractor E2E tests.

It is because Timeshift is not a node module, so it cannot be required, so I created a fork, enjoy: https://github.com/cvakiitho/TimeShift-js/blob/master/timeshift.js

Comment: Ok thank you! So how can I use your branch in my e2e tests?

Comment: I mean, where is the best place to place the TimeShift.js file? How can I use it in my code?

Comment: I have it inside my helpers directory: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32335796/2374517

But I'm using it inside E2E tests following page object pattern, so I'm not sure in your case.

Comment: ok.. where is you helpers directory w.r.t. the actual step.js file?. Because I still get a "undefined is not a function" error

Comment: I have no idea how your project is structured, but according to the code you posted you should have it next to utils.js.

Comment: and that's correct. Funny thing is that even with only the require() line on top I get the "undefined is not a function" error

Comment: seems like the line "var root = this" at the beginning of the timeshift.js code returns "undefined"

Comment: That`s weird, not repro on my side.

Comment: the offending line is timeshift.js:21 which I tracked down to the var root = this; but I might be wrong. The actual error appears at line 21

Comment: I've just edited my question. I get the undefined error even opening the tests.html file straight away form a fresh copy of develop

Comment: You have to call timeshift functions with thimeshift, not TimeShift. 
It is dependent on how you require it.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I just launched the tests.html example file which comes with the library itself. It's a test suite for the library but it gives me the same "undefined" error message. I have included a snapshot of the error in my question above

Comment: Well that is not what you were asking for in your question is it?
Tests are not fixed in my fork. 

Maybe you have to require Timeshift into variable named TimeShift with correct capitalization, because of that `root=this;`

Comment: I'm requiring it like this: var TimeShift = require('../timeshift.js');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94816/discussion-between-cvakiitho-and-gianluca-ghettini).